# Sms sending fails from php

Tags: php, sms-gateway

I am using `cs-networks` `SMS Gateway Api` to send messages from my website, I'm generating url and when I copy to browser it works fine, but when I'm trying to send it from PHP code, it fails.
My url is: `http://api.cs-networks.net:9011/bin/send?USERNAME=my_username&PASSWORD=mypassword&SOURCEADDR=AMANATI&DESTADDR=user_number&MESSAGE=Hello+World`

```
<?php
    $api_url = "http://api.cs-networks.net:9011/bin/send?USERNAME=my_username&PASSWORD=mypassword&SOURCEADDR=AMANATI&DESTADDR=user_number&MESSAGE=Hello+World";

    $result = file_get_contents($api_url); // fails

    // also fails
    $ch = curl_init($api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Can anybody tell me how to reffer this url from php to make it work?

Comment: is cURL is enabled on your server?

Comment: first remove true credentials from url in the question posted:)

Comment: thanks for advice, just removed

Comment: When you say it fails, what is the error code associated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** So I contacted to my web hosting provider and explained them my problem, they told me that it could be because of closed port (90), so they opened port 90 and everything worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `fopen()` as it handles URL's too?

`$result = fopen($api_url, "r");`

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)